# How do I set the distance transform formula when using CV_DIST_USER on OpenCV's distanceTransform method?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to compute some distance transformations using OpenCV in a C++ program developed in XCode 4.6.2. So far I'm able to compute successfully all the distance types that came with OpenCV, but I saw that it's possible to use CV_DIST_USER, which is an user defined distance, as the computed distance type.

So, my question is: how do I define the formula of this distance? I couldn't find anything in the OpenCV docs or website.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CV_DIST_USER` is not supported by `cv::distanceTransform()`. It is only implemented for the C API function [`cvDistTransform()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvdistt#void%20cvDistTransform%28const%20CvArr%2a%20src,%20CvArr%2a%20dst,%20int%20distance_type,%20int%20mask_size,%20const%20float%2a%20mask,%20CvArr%2a%20labels,%20int%20labelType%29). If you wanted to use the C function, you would pass in a `float` array, which is the mask defining your distance function.

Comment: Thanks, @Aurelius! I tried it this way: `cvDistTransform(&l_ThresholdedImage, &l_distanceTransformedImage, CV_DIST_USER, 3, mask)` where the first two parameters are of the type `Mat` and `mask` is a float array composed of the values 1.0 and 1.4 (I'm trying the quasi-euclidean transform). Unfortunately it gives me this:

`OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat`

Any toughs on this? 
Thanks again!

Comment: @LiordinoNeto Functions in the C API require `IplImage*` for the image data, not `cv::Mat`. You need to declare `IplImage im = l_ThresholdedImage`, and then pass `&im` to the function. If you keep having problems, it's probably better if you post a separate question.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem continues. I'll create another question for it. Thanks!